# Jest saying "Not a function" when it is defined as function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am writing jest for this simple function:

```
function isVowel(ch) {
  ch = ch.toUpperCase();

  return ch == "A" || ch == "E" || ch == "I" || ch == "O" || ch == "U";
}
```

this is the jest:

```
const isVowel = require("./isVowel");
test("a is vowel", () => {
  const ch = isVowel("a");
  expect(ch).toBe("A");
});
```

on running, it gives error:  TypeError: isVowel is not a function

how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you exported the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you write your code in `commonjs` format due to the way you `require` it in your test file so you just simply export like this:

```js
// isVowel.js

function isVowel(ch) {
  ch = ch.toUpperCase();

  return ch == "A" || ch == "E" || ch == "I" || ch == "O" || ch == "U";
}

module.exports = isVowel;
```